# webrtc pc.onaddstream window.URL.createObjectURl with remote video not showing

Tags: javascript, video, webrtc

I'm trying to set a basic video chat example. Currently trying to chat between two chrome tabs on the same computer.
Everything looks good until I get the remote video stream, and when I put it in the `remoteVideo` element using `URL.createObjectURI` I just get blank nothing. No video showing although I got the remote stream event.

What can cause this? Any ideas? Please help!

Here is the log of the signalling:

**caller:**

```
    Got userMedia
    Registered signaling room
    BY_WebRTC.startSession HOQfXIe3uoLMtDgSlHVH+A== true
    VM9840:128 tryStart: created peer connection.
    VM9840:150 Created RTCPeerConnnection
    VM9840:133 tryStart: added stream to peer connection.
    VM9840:170 Sending offer to peer
    VM9840:184 sending sdp RTCSessionDescription {type: "offer", sdp: "v=0
    ↵o=- 3416476007859143551 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    ↵s…9521 label:a8a8592f-d78d-40b2-bc1c-1a7c33772201
    ↵"}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:3054232416 1 udp 2122260223 169.254.80.8… generation 0 ufrag Ab1ql0yuiJZgNzDJ network-id 2", sdpMid: "audio", sdpMLineIndex: 0}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:3708192848 1 udp 2122194687 172.19.67.39… generation 0 ufrag Ab1ql0yuiJZgNzDJ network-id 1", sdpMid: "audio", sdpMLineIndex: 0}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:3054232416 2 udp 2122260222 169.254.80.8… generation 0 ufrag Ab1ql0yuiJZgNzDJ network-id 2", sdpMid: "audio", sdpMLineIndex: 0}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:3708192848 2 udp 2122194686 172.19.67.39… generation 0 ufrag Ab1ql0yuiJZgNzDJ network-id 1", sdpMid: "audio", sdpMLineIndex: 0}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:3054232416 1 udp 2122260223 169.254.80.8… generation 0 ufrag Ab1ql0yuiJZgNzDJ network-id 2", sdpMid: "video", sdpMLineIndex: 1}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:3708192848 1 udp 2122194687 172.19.67.39… generation 0 ufrag Ab1ql0yuiJZgNzDJ network-id 1", sdpMid: "video", sdpMLineIndex: 1}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:3054232416 2 udp 2122260222 169.254.80.8… generation 0 ufrag Ab1ql0yuiJZgNzDJ network-id 2", sdpMid: "video", sdpMLineIndex: 1}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:3708192848 2 udp 2122194686 172.19.67.39… generation 0 ufrag Ab1ql0yuiJZgNzDJ network-id 1", sdpMid: "video", sdpMLineIndex: 1}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:4169670544 1 tcp 1518280447 169.254.80.8… generation 0 ufrag Ab1ql0yuiJZgNzDJ network-id 2", sdpMid: "audio", sdpMLineIndex: 0}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:2474996896 1 tcp 1518214911 172.19.67.39… generation 0 ufrag Ab1ql0yuiJZgNzDJ network-id 1", sdpMid: "audio", sdpMLineIndex: 0}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:4169670544 2 tcp 1518280446 169.254.80.8… generation 0 ufrag Ab1ql0yuiJZgNzDJ network-id 2", sdpMid: "audio", sdpMLineIndex: 0}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:2474996896 2 tcp 1518214910 172.19.67.39… generation 0 ufrag Ab1ql0yuiJZgNzDJ network-id 1", sdpMid: "audio", sdpMLineIndex: 0}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:4169670544 1 tcp 1518280447 169.254.80.8… generation 0 ufrag Ab1ql0yuiJZgNzDJ network-id 2", sdpMid: "video", sdpMLineIndex: 1}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:2474996896 1 tcp 1518214911 172.19.67.39… generation 0 ufrag Ab1ql0yuiJZgNzDJ network-id 1", sdpMid: "video", sdpMLineIndex: 1}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:4169670544 2 tcp 1518280446 169.254.80.8… generation 0 ufrag Ab1ql0yuiJZgNzDJ network-id 2", sdpMid: "video", sdpMLineIndex: 1}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:2474996896 2 tcp 1518214910 172.19.67.39… generation 0 ufrag Ab1ql0yuiJZgNzDJ network-id 1", sdpMid: "video", sdpMLineIndex: 1}
    VM9840:110 Received answer
    VM9840:207 Remote stream added. MediaStreamEvent {stream: MediaStream, type: "addstream", target: RTCPeerConnection, currentTarget: RTCPeerConnection, eventPhase: 2…}
    VM9840:191 handleIceCandidate event:  null
    VM9840:202 End of candidates.
```

**callee:**

```
Got User Media
Registered signaling room
Received offer
webrtc.js?v=2.22:128 tryStart: created peer connection.
webrtc.js?v=2.22:150 Created RTCPeerConnnection
webrtc.js?v=2.22:133 tryStart: added stream to peer connection.
webrtc.js?v=2.22:175 Sending answer to peer.
webrtc.js?v=2.22:207 Remote stream added. MediaStreamEvent {stream: MediaStream, type: "addstream", target: RTCPeerConnection, currentTarget: RTCPeerConnection, eventPhase: 2…}
webrtc.js?v=2.22:184 sending sdp RTCSessionDescription {type: "answer", sdp: "v=0
↵o=- 1405083852183288173 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
↵s…5319 label:9a0427e6-be00-4a66-a862-77c1deafb89d
↵"}
webrtc.js?v=2.22:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:3054232416 1 udp 2122260223 169.254.80.8… generation 0 ufrag wf8+wbbJ2eepjam8 network-id 2", sdpMid: "audio", sdpMLineIndex: 0}
webrtc.js?v=2.22:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:3708192848 1 udp 2122194687 172.19.67.39… generation 0 ufrag wf8+wbbJ2eepjam8 network-id 1", sdpMid: "audio", sdpMLineIndex: 0}
webrtc.js?v=2.22:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:4169670544 1 tcp 1518280447 169.254.80.8… generation 0 ufrag wf8+wbbJ2eepjam8 network-id 2", sdpMid: "audio", sdpMLineIndex: 0}
webrtc.js?v=2.22:191 handleIceCandidate event:  RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:2474996896 1 tcp 1518214911 172.19.67.39… generation 0 ufrag wf8+wbbJ2eepjam8 network-id 1", sdpMid: "audio", sdpMLineIndex: 0}
webrtc.js?v=2.22:191 handleIceCandidate event:  null
webrtc.js?v=2.22:202 End of candidates.
```

**code (starts at startSession with isInitiator=true for caller - after got local media):**

```
var BY_WebRTC = {

    // consts
    pc_config: {
        'iceServers': [
                        { url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' }]
    },
    pc_constraints: { 'optional': [{ 'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': true }] },
    sdpConstraints: {
        'mandatory': {
            // Set up audio and video regardless of what devices are present.
            'OfferToReceiveAudio': true,
            'OfferToReceiveVideo': true
        }
    },

    localStream: null,
    remoteStream: null,

    isStarted: false,
    isInitiator: false,

    realtimeEventId: null, // current conversation object realtime server room id

    pc: null, // peer connection

    getUserMedia: function (video, audio, callback) {
        var constraints = { video: video, audio: audio };       
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {
            BY_WebRTC.localStream = stream;
            callback(stream);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("BY_WebRTC:getUserMedia Error!", error);
        });

    },

    startSession: function (encryptedObjectId, isInitiator) {

        // store the realtime event id
        BY_WebRTC.realtimeEventId = { groupType: 'object', groupId: encryptedObjectId, eventType: "webrtc" };
        BY_WebRTC.encryptedObjectId = encryptedObjectId;

        // register chat room for webrtc signaling
        nowManager.registerGroupEvents([BY_WebRTC.realtimeEventId], BY_WebRTC.realtimeWebRTC_EventHandler);

        console.log("BY_WebRTC.startSession", encryptedObjectId, isInitiator);

        if (isInitiator) {
            BY_WebRTC.isInitiator = true;
            BY_WebRTC.tryStart();
        }
    },

    realtimeWebRTC_EventHandler: function (message) {

        if (message === 'start') {
            BY_WebRTC.tryStart();
        }
        else if (message.type === 'offer') {
            console.log('Received offer');

            if (!BY_WebRTC.isInitiator && !BY_WebRTC.isStarted) {
                BY_WebRTC.tryStart();
            }

            BY_WebRTC.pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
            BY_WebRTC.sendAnswer();
        }
        else if (message.type === 'answer' && isStarted) {
            console.log('Received answer');
            BY_WebRTC.pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
        }
        else if (message.type === 'candidate' && BY_WebRTC.isStarted) {
            var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
                sdpMLineIndex: message.label,
                candidate: message.candidate
            });
            BY_WebRTC.pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
        }
        else if (message === 'bye' && BY_WebRTC.isStarted) {
            BY_WebRTC.handleRemoteHangup();
        }
    },

    tryStart: function () {

        if (!BY_WebRTC.isStarted && typeof BY_WebRTC.localStream != null) {
            console.log("tryStart: created peer connection.");

            BY_WebRTC.createPeerConnection();
            BY_WebRTC.pc.addStream(BY_WebRTC.localStream);

            console.log("tryStart: added stream to peer connection.");

            isStarted = true;

            if (BY_WebRTC.isInitiator) {
                BY_WebRTC.sendOffer();
            }
        }
    },

    createPeerConnection: function () {
        try {
            var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(this.pc_config);
            pc.onicecandidate = this.handleIceCandidate;
            pc.onaddstream = this.handleRemoteStreamAdded;
            pc.onremovestream = this.handleRemoteStreamRemoved;

            console.log('Created RTCPeerConnnection');

            BY_WebRTC.pc = pc;

        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: ' + e.message);
            alert('Cannot create RTCPeerConnection object.');
            return;
        }
    },

    handleCreateOfferError: function (event) {
        console.log('sendOffer() error: ', e);
    },

    handleSendAnswerError: function (event) {
        console.log('sendAnswer() error: ', e);
    },

    sendOffer: function () {
        console.log('Sending offer to peer');
        BY_WebRTC.pc.createOffer(BY_WebRTC.setLocalAndSendMessage, BY_WebRTC.handleCreateOfferError);
    },

    sendAnswer: function () {
        console.log('Sending answer to peer.');
        BY_WebRTC.pc.createAnswer(BY_WebRTC.setLocalAndSendMessage, BY_WebRTC.handleSendAnswerError, BY_WebRTC.sdpConstraints);
    },

    setLocalAndSendMessage: function (sessionDescription) {
        // Set Opus as the preferred codec in SDP if Opus is present.
        sessionDescription.sdp = BY_WebRTC.preferOpus(sessionDescription.sdp);
        BY_WebRTC.pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);

        console.log("sending sdp", sessionDescription);

        nowManager.sendGroupEvent(BY_WebRTC.realtimeEventId, sessionDescription);
    },

    handleIceCandidate: function (event) {

        console.log('handleIceCandidate event: ', event.candidate);

        if (event.candidate) {
            nowManager.sendGroupEvent(BY_WebRTC.realtimeEventId, {
                type: 'candidate',
                label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
                candidate: event.candidate.candidate
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('End of candidates.');
        }
    },

    handleRemoteStreamAdded: function (event) {
        console.log('Remote stream added.', event);

        // todo: send callback event after got remote stream
        document.querySelector('#remoteVideo').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
        BY_WebRTC.remoteStream = event.stream;

        $("#remoteVideo").show();
    },

    handleRemoteStreamRemoved: function (event) {
        console.log('Remote stream removed. Event: ', event);
    },

    hangup: function () {
        console.log('Hanging up.');
        this.stop();
        nowManager.sendGroupEvent(this.realtimeEventId, "bye");
    },

    handleRemoteHangup: function () {
        //  console.log('Session terminated.');
        // stop();
        // isInitiator = false;
    },

    stop: function () {
        BY_WebRTC.isStarted = false;
        BY_WebRTC.pc.close();
        BY_WebRTC.pc = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `event.stream` at `handleRemoteStreamAdded` function?

Comment: it is the data of the RTCPeerConnection addstream event. i think it supposed to be this way and also the event.stream i recieve is an object and the url.createObjectUrl works and return a blob url... but when i put it in the video.src there is no video showing

Comment: Is `event.source` a `Blob` or an `ArrayBuffer`?

Comment: Did you try `video.play()`, or `autoplay`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the answer!
Due to some small bug ( i didn't init isStarted = true ) I did not add the ice candidates. this was causing the problem.